# Program that simulates the usage of a prepaid mobile. Wrong output

Tags: java

How to output: CreditsLeft: 34.50
               Total call duration: 12 mins.
               Rate per call: 6.50
               Number of text messages sent: 0

```
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class MobilePhone 
{
DecimalFormat df= new DecimalFormat("###,###.00");
private double creditsLeft;
private int totalMinCall;
private double ratePerCall;
private int totalOfTextSent;

public MobilePhone()
{
    creditsLeft=0.00;
    totalMinCall=0;
    ratePerCall=6.50;
    totalOfTextSent=0;
}
public void load(double pesos)
{
    creditsLeft= creditsLeft + pesos;
}
public void call(int minutes)
{
    double credits= creditsLeft;
    double rate= ratePerCall;

    if(credits<rate)
    {
        System.out.println("You Have Insufficient Ballance");
    }
    else
    {
        rate= rate*minutes;
        creditsLeft= creditsLeft - rate;
    }
}
public double getLoadLeft()
{
    return creditsLeft;
}
public int getTotalMinutesCalled()
{
    return totalMinCall;
}
public void printSummary()
{
    System.out.println("Credits left: P"+df.format(creditsLeft));
    System.out.println("Total call duration: "+totalMinCall+" mins");
    System.out.println("Rate per call: P"+df.format(ratePerCall));
    System.out.print("Number of text messages sent: ");
}
public void changeRate(double newCallRate)
{
    newCallRate=ratePerCall;
}
public void sendTextMessage()
{
    totalOfTextSent++;
    creditsLeft= creditsLeft - 1;
}
public int getNumOfTextMessages()
{
    return totalOfTextSent;
}
}
```

This is the main

```
    public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MobilePhone mp = new MobilePhone();
    mp.load(34.50);
    mp.call(12);
    mp.printSummary();
    System.out.println(mp.getNumOfTextMessages());
}
}
```

The output i got is this one:

Credits left: P-43.50 
Total call duration: 0 mins.
Rate per call: P6.50
Number of text messages sent: 0

It supposed to be like this:

Credits left: P34.50
Total call duration: 12 mins.
Rate per call: P6.50
Number of text messages sent: 0

Comment: This is Java, not Javascript!

Comment: okay thanks . sorry .

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the value given in the     mp.load() in the     main() method.
Instead of 34.50 , please give 112.50. Then you will get the output you want

Comment: I deleted subtracting the rate of call from creditsLeft, i already got the output, Thanks again for codes added. Sorry for my bad english :DD

Answer (score 1):

just a few hints
 - add the minutes in the call function to totalMinCall
 - concerning the credits: this isn't possible if you don't load more than 34.50... so most probably the initial amount hast to be heigher

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `totalMinCall` stays at 0 because your code never changes it. You need to add some code to update `totalMinCall`.

The credits left calculation appears to me to be correct. You need to top your phone with more credit in the `main` method!

Comment: Thanks :D . i just deleted subtracting rate on creditsLeft. Is this correct?

Comment: no, it's not correct, as Roman Pickl said the *initial amount* has to be higher. Like I said, in the main method. The initial amount, *not* the calculation.